# How to level up past 42 in Borderlands 2?

Tags: borderlands-2

I am level 42 and have completed every mission except for Terramorphous, which is Level 50. What can I do to level up more so I can beat it? Leveling takes so long: I have beat the dragon so many times I am bored of making runs against it.

Do I go back through Claptrap's again? I'd like to begin True Vault Hunter Mode but I must beat Terramorphous first.

Comment: You can switch back and forth between modes; you don't need to have completed everything, you can go back when you've got a shiny new gun or badass new skill in order to beat off a particular enemy in a lower difficulty mode.

Comment: Aren't the downvotes a bit mean in this case? as while some research is expected, i think this is a more fundermental misunderstanding of how the game expects you to progress

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You restart in **True Vault Hunter Mode**, the second difficulty. (Go to main menu, Select Character, re-select your character, and it should ask you which difficulty you want to play in).

TVHM is the same game, but starts at level 30, and ends at level 50. Also, some more difficult variations of enemies are introduced, like Armored Psychos. All elemental resistances and vulnerabilities are more pronounced - it is even more stupid now to shoot armor with fire, and fire does even more bonus damage to flesh. After you beat The Warrior in TVHM, entire game world (including first areas) is scaled to level 50 - this is informally known as "playthrough 2.5".

At the release of BL2, 50 was max level, so that's why Terramorphous is scaled to 50 even on Normal. Currently, there is also an **Ultimate Vault Hunter Mode**, the third difficulty (but I believe, you have to buy DLC to access that). UVHM spans from level 50 to level 61 or 72 (depending on DLC), and is even harder - enemies regenerate, but Slag now *triples* the incoming damage.

Comment: WOW !  Thank You Very Much , I have been trying to figure this out for some time, I really did not think I would get answers here like other places I have tried, so I am very Impressed & thankful .